# xslt 2.0 sum() works incorrect with float values

Tags: xml, excel, sum, xslt-2.0, obiee

I have a source xml like:

```
<group>
    <group_type_id>1</group_type_id>
    <measure1>4324.44352</measure1>
    <measure2>0</measure2>
    <measure3>55.3</measure3>
</group>
<group>
    <group_type_id>1</group_type_id>
    <measure1>535.777</measure1>
    <measure2>0.509</measure2>
    <measure3>707</measure3>
</group>
<group>
    <group_type_id>2</group_type_id>
    <measure1>3345.6</measure1>
    <measure2>0.1301</measure2>
    <measure3>1000.03</measure3>
</group>
<group>
    <group_type_id>2</group_type_id>
    <measure1>3478.1</measure1>
    <measure2>654.754634</measure2>
    <measure3>890</measure3>
</group>
```

I want to transform it to excel-readable .xml with sum totals by measure1,2,3. I try to use this xslt code:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-by="group_type_id">
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:Style="someStyle">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/measure1)" />  
            </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Style="someStyle">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/measure2)" />  
            </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Style="someStyle">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/measure3)" />  
            </Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

But in result i take in my cells values with lost number fraction. For sum of measure 1 in group_type_id=1 it must
be 4324.44352+535.777= 4860.22052. But i getting something like 4860220520000000.
I've tried different functions like:

```
sum(current-group()/measure1/text())
sum(number(current-group()/measure1/text()))
sum(number-format(current-group()/measure1/text()),'####.####')
```

e.t.c.
but it all given me same result.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post minimal but complete snippets allowing us to reproduce the problem. Also state which XSLT 2.0 processor you use.

Comment: It is Oracle BI 11 Publisher xslt processor

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem at http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5Q, result is `<Data ss:Type="Number">4860.22052</Data>`. So check with your XSLT processor's support. Or try a workaround `sum(current-group()/measure1/xs:decimal(.))` (declare `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`).

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I will try it soon.